# How to get a div's value which was returned in from a API pull into another .js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Very new to this so excuse the misuse of terms and such.

So I have a initial .js that pulls my data here.

```
require(['jquery', 'example/api'],

    function($, example) {
        function doPull(pointid,pointHTMLid) {
            var htmlid = '#' + pointHTMLid;
            exampleAPI.defaultApi.getCurrentValue(poinXid).then(function(currentValue) {

                /*
                currentValue is a large JSON object that looks like this:
                {"name":"Mode",
                "value":1,
                "type":"Multistate",
                "path":"/example/",
                "timestamp":1440298005485,
                "id":"DP_509043",
                "deviceName":"VirtualUnit",
                "unit":"",
                "status":"ok",
                "renderedValue":"1"}
            */

                var output = null;
                var multi = {'0': 'Mode 1', '1': 'Mode 2', '2': 'Mode 3'};
                var binary = {'zero': 'Off', 'one': 'On'};

                switch (currentValue.type) {
                    case "Multistate":
                        output = (multi[currentValue.renderedValue]);
                        break;
                    case "Binary":
                        output = (binary[currentValue.renderedValue]);
                        break;
                    case "Numeric":
                        output = currentValue.renderedValue;
                        break;
                    default:
                        output = "Sorry...";
                }

                //$(htmlid).text(JSON.stringify(currentValue));
                $(htmlid).text(output);


            }).fail(exampleAPI.logError);

        }

        function allThePulls() {

            doPull('pointone', 'mode');

        }


        allThePulls();

        setInterval(allThePulls, 5000);


    });
```

Now I have a div which is returning the rendered value.

which returns something like: Mode: Mode 1

If I was wanting to make another js file and set the content of this div to a variable how would I do this? Sorry again if this isn't enough information or my terms are incorrect

here is the second .js I am trying o get the div value in:

```
require(['jquery', 'example/api', 'overviewpull.js'],function($,doPull){
    function overlayMode($) {


        var mt = $('#mode').text();

        if (mt = "Mode 1") {
            $("#overlay").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#overlay").hide();

        }
    }
    overlayMode();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

hope you are using require.js framework.
if you want to add another js file, you can access the initial .js file function from the new.js file.

in new.js file

```
require(['jquery', 'example/api', 'inital.js'],function($,....){
  //call the function from the inital.js which returns
  // the div content and use that value here. 
});
```

Comment: I have added the new .js code. Again sorry if this code could be way off.

Comment: Try $("mode1").html() or $("#mode1").val();          because .text() returns the dependents values of the matching I'd refer http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: I am still not getting anything with that :(